# how to get current extension of template generation

Tags: visual-studio, t4

With the following code I can set the file extension to "ddd":

```
<#@ output extension=".ddd" #>
```

or

```
Host.SetFileExtension(".ddd");
```

Is there a way to obtain the file extension, that is currently active? Something like

```
var ext = Host.GetFileExtension();
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell there are no public methods or properties to get the FileExtension.

`<#@ output extension="ddd"#>` calls `Host.SetFileExtension("ddd")`.

However, the Host runs in another AppDomain which also complicates any method to retrieve it using reflection.